# Linear operator on $\ell^{\infty}$ is not surjective – well-definition of inverse operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, lp-spaces

Let $T: \ell^{\infty} \rightarrow \ell^{\infty}$, such that $Tx = \left(\frac{1}{n} x_n\right)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$. **Claim:** $T$ is not surjective.

I have been trying to come up with $y \in \ell^{\infty}$ such that there is no $x \in \ell^{\infty}$ with $Tx = y$.

Comment: $x$ is in $\ell^\infty$.

Comment: Sorry, I was confusing the norm with $\| \cdot \|_1$

Comment: Hint: Same strategy but take the constant sequsnce  $y=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y$ be the constant sequence $1$. If there was $x\in\ell^\infty$ such that $T(x)=y$ then we would have $\frac{1}{n}x_n=1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and hence $x_n=n$. But this means $x$ is not a bounded sequence, i.e not in $\ell^\infty$. A contradiction.

Comment: Now, this is what is confusing to me a little. Why is it exactly that $\frac{1}{n}x_n=1$ for all $n$?

Comment: An element in $\ell^\infty$ is a bounded sequence $x=(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ of complex numbers. The operator $T$ maps the sequence $(x_n)$ to the sequence $(\frac{1}{n}x_n)$. So if we assume $T(x)=y$ where $x=(x_n)$ and where $y=(y_n)$ is the constant sequence $1$ then it means $\frac{1}{n}x_n=y_n=1$ for all $n$.